# Update mysql table when row inserted or updated

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have three tables.

first table **Pickup**

```
    ----------------
   id  | no |    date   |
   --------------------
    2  | a  |  15/02/15 |
    2  | b  |  18/02/15 |
    2  | c  |  19/02/15 |
    3  | d  |           |
    2  | e  |           |
    ---------------
```

second table **track**

```
    ----------------
   id  | no |    date   |
   --------------------
    2  | a  |  15/02/15 |
    2  | b  |  18/02/15 |
    2  | c  |  19/02/15 |
    3  | d  |           |
    2  | e  |           |
    ---------------
```

when updating date column in pickup table the same value has to update automatically on  track table **WHERE id = id AND no = no** condition

Comment: Use trigger. For more details :https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html

Answer (score 1):

You'll need two triggers, one for the insert:

```
DELIMITER //
create trigger trackInsert after insert on pickup
for each row
begin
  insert into track values (NEW.id, NEW.no, NEW.`date`);
end//
DELIMITER ;
```

and then one for the update:

```
DELIMITER //
create trigger trackUpdate after update on pickup
for each row
begin
  update track SET `date` = NEW.`date` WHERE id = NEW.id AND no = NEW.no;
end//
DELIMITER ;
```

Or, alternatively, you could just accept the fact that track contains a foreign key that references pickup, and not duplicate the date value.